# CMD file has 256 character length limit

Tags: windows, path, cmd, business-intelligence, informatica

I am generating a .CMD file using Informatica 9.5. It creates two MOVE commands (in the same file, 2 separate lines) with paths being picked from parameter files. The total length of the MOVE command exceeds 256 characters, and when the .CMD file is generated, it truncates this path when it reaches that character limit.

How do I resolve this issue?

The expression I am using in Informatica transformation is:

```
'MOVE "'  ||  $$FROM_PATH1  || 'FOO.ZIP"  "'  || $$TO_PATH  ||   'FOO' ||  '.ZIP"'  || CHR(10)      ||  
'MOVE "'  ||  $$FROM_PATH2  || 'BAR.ZIP"  "'  || $$TO_PATH  ||   'BAR'  ||  '.ZIP"'
```

When the CMD file is generated, it truncates the second variable and looks something like this:

```
MOVE "\\ABC\XYZ\FOLDER1\FOO.ZIP" "\\ABC\XYZ\FOLFOO.ZIP"
MOVE "\\ABC\XYZ\FOLDER2\BAR.ZIP" "\\ABC\XYZ\FOLBAR.ZIP"
```

Assuming that **$$TO_PATH** was *\\ABC\XYZ\FOLDER3\*, notice that it has truncated the variable path but has still added the hard-coded characters. What gives?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the tool you're using to generate the .cmd file (or how you're using it).

Comment: If the total length of the MOVE command is less than 256 characters, it works perfectly fine. So, either Informatica is setting the line character limit to 256 somewhere or CMD files can't exceed 256 characters in each line.

Comment: You can test this yourself by typing the echo command at a cmd.exe prompt and seeing if you can echo more than 255 characters. You will see that it can. Therefore, the limitation is in the tool you're using to generate the .cmd file, not in cmd.exe itself.

Comment: You are correct, I'll check Informatica resources to resolve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Isn't simply any of the expression's ports too short?

Comment: The expression transformation as well as the target both have string datatype precision set to 1000 in the port. These are the only two transformations involved with this CMD file, as far as I am aware. Am I missing anything though?

But then, if the port was too small, wouldn't it just truncate when it hit the limit? Why would it append the FOO.ZIP in the end? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Thank you for your answer. I went in and looked at the parameter being used in that transformation and that particular parameter indeed had wrong precision. Not on the expression or Target port but on the parameter precision itself. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is your target port is defined as 255 characters or another transformation during your mapping is limited to 255 characters.

Increase the size of the offending ports to fix your issue.

Comment: All the transformations and target ports involved with this file have string datatype precision set to 1000.